# Partial transfer when using Nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2016

I have a problem with loading in my website through a Nginx proxy. The website is hosted on a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter server in IIS. When the loading problem happens I have the issue that for example an image won’t load in and I get this error in Firefox in the console "NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER". This also could happen on other files like the main.js. The problem only occurs when the Nginx server is being used together with the Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. But when I access the site with an IP address directly this problem is gone and it works as expected.

I tried using different Nginx settings but nothing helped (also didn’t make it worse or better). The only thing I could find out is when I host the website on a Windows 10 machine also in IIS (VM on the Windows Server 2016 Datacenter) the problem does not occur. I also tried different Windows Server versions and editions like: Windows Server 2019 and 2022. Both of them I tried in the standard edition and datacenter edition. I disabled on the Windows server 2016 Datacenter the firewall and Windows defender, in IIS any restriction I could find. But on the Windows 10 VM this all wasn’t necessary.